# Android inserting 5000 records in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi i would like to know the best way to update listview with 5000 record from the database,do i need to query all the records first and update the listview (what adapter should i use), without any pagenation or using infinitescroll library.and also is there any limit for sqllite, what is the max limit of sqllite

Comment: Wow....so many questions in a single question!

Comment: i prefer loading asynchronously

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes you must implement a Cursor Adapter. That will help loading your list properly without you caring for loops or lazyloading.

Comment: Shouldn't CursorAdapter do the magic?

Comment: i prefer pull to refresh list.

Comment: Or use load more list...

Comment: can someone draw a picture of an end-user, who is able to look through 5k records on a mobile device?

Comment: there is a limit tied with a CursorWindow or rather a Parcel it is read from / written to